# Is using arithmetic faster than storing a variable?

Tags: c, optimization, bit-manipulation

In C (or possibly in general) is it faster to use arithmetic to get a value, or call it from an array/variable?

For example, if I had

```
int myarray[7] = {16};
int mysixteen = 16;
```

then I can get 16 in a number of different ways

```
myarray[#]
mysixteen
16
1 << 4
10 + 6
```

Logically 16 would be the fastest, but that's not always convenient or plausible for a set of numbers. An example of where this might be relevant is precomputing tables. Say you need bitmasks for 64 bits, you could fill an array

```
for (int i = 0; i < 64; ++i) {
    mask[i] = 1 << i;
}
```

and make calls to the array in the future, or make a macro

```
#define mask(b) (1 << b)
```

and call that.

Comment: Don't worry about it! Don't try to outsmart the compiler. You'll fail. Do whatever makes you code easiest to read. Come back and do sneaky optimisation once you find you have a speed problem.

Comment: @John3136 I'm actually not working on anything right now, just playing around in gcc optimizing/timing for fun.

Comment: In general, a small (less than 256, depending on the hardware architecture) literal value will be as fast or faster than any other option.  Of course, most compilers will pre-compute constant expressions into literal values where possible.

Comment: Take a look at some crypto libraries, Almost all of them store tables to speed up the encryption.

Comment: Re the macro approach, understand that the macro is substituted at compile time, so it would be exactly equivalent to coding the expression at every use.

Comment: I very much doubt that a table for bitmasks will be anyway faster than the bitshift itself. A table of trigonometric functions maybe...

Comment: If the processor has a [barrel shifter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter) and the `int` size is <= than the native size, the computation is typically faster than lookup.  Without the barrel shifter, variable shifts take N ticks.  What is really best is to profile on your target platform, realizing that another system may prefer another approach.  Concerning optimization, watch out for spending lots of effort on the trees and not seeing the forest.

Comment: @rodrigo ... correct bitops (&,|,^,~,<<,>>,...) are usually 1 cycle and multiple can be executed per cycle, but I wouldn't classify bitops as "arithmetic", just manipulating bits (which can be done in such a way to perform arithmetic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, any of

- 16
- 1 << 4
- 10 + 6

Will result in a literal `16` because the compiler most certainly implements an optimization called [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding).

The performance of

- mysixteen
- myarray[n]

is *probably* lower depending on where the value of those variables is stored. In memory? If so, is the memory in any of the CPU caches? Or is it stored in one of the CPU registers? There's no definitive answer.

I general, for a *specific* program, you can always see what your compiler gives you - but note that this may change a lot depending on surrounding code and your optimization flags.

To try it yourself, consider this small program:

```
int f() { return 16; }

int g() { return 1 << 4; }

int h() { return 10 + 6; }

int i() {
    int myarray[7] = { 16 };
    return myarray[3];
}

int j() {
    int mysixteen = 16;
    return mysixteen;
}
```

If I compile it using gcc 4.7.2 and then check the disassembly, like

```
$ gcc -c so19802742.c -o so19802742.o
$ objdump --disassemble so19802742.o
```

I get this:

```
0000000000000000 <f>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   b8 10 00 00 00          mov    $0x10,%eax
   9:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   a:   c3                      retq   

000000000000000b <g>:
   b:   55                      push   %rbp
   c:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   f:   b8 10 00 00 00          mov    $0x10,%eax
  14:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  15:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000016 <h>:
  16:   55                      push   %rbp
  17:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  1a:   b8 10 00 00 00          mov    $0x10,%eax
  1f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  20:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000021 <i>:
  21:   55                      push   %rbp
  22:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  25:   48 c7 45 e0 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
  2c:   00 
  2d:   48 c7 45 e8 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
  34:   00 
  35:   48 c7 45 f0 00 00 00    movq   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
  3c:   00 
  3d:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
  44:   c7 45 e0 10 00 00 00    movl   $0x10,-0x20(%rbp)
  4b:   8b 45 ec                mov    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
  4e:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4f:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000050 <j>:
  50:   55                      push   %rbp
  51:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  54:   c7 45 fc 10 00 00 00    movl   $0x10,-0x4(%rbp)
  5b:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  5e:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  5f:   c3                      retq
```

Note how due to constant folding, `f`, `g` and `h` yield exactly the same machine code. The array access in `i` causes the most machine code (but not necessarily the slowest!) and `j` is kind of inbetween.

However, this is without any more complicated code optimizations at all! The code generated when compiling with e.g. `-O2` may be *totally* different because the compiler notices that calls to any of the five functions are equivalent to just using the constant `16`!

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about these things. The compiler is smart enough in most cases. Even basic operations like multiply are sometimes optimized to use shifts, as it is more efficient this way.

Speaking about your example, the array version would require a lot of memory access, which is very slow. The macro will be faster in the most cases, depending on the number of accesses.